# How can I find out if a user deleted his consent on Future Payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

As the title says, I would like to check if the user has deleted his consent on Future Payments in his PayPal profile. I am currently only testing in the Sandbox environment with the iOS mSDK and the Java REST API SDK.

I expected that creating new accessTokens using the refreshToken would throw an error, but it is still possible. Then I tried to query Userinformation, but this is also possible.

If I create a new Payment, then I get an error (REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING). But isn't there a way to check that without creating a transaction each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no good solution for this problem without using IPN (not tested yet). I am now using a workaround as described here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/189.

Conclusion: An accessToken generated with the refreshToken has the value "900" in the field "expires_in" if the user consent still exists. Otherwise, it is "28800".

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can always call updateBillingAgreement API to check whether it is active or not. 
Paypal also has IPN setup to adhere this kind of notifications.https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside

Comment: thanks for your answer. I could not find a way how I can get the Agreement-Id using the refreshToken. Could you please give me a hint?